# wxpython: how to access a window when a dialog is open

Tags: dialog, wxpython, accessibility

I understand that the parent of a dialog should be inaccessible when ShowModal(). However, my program is required to  give access to a separate window, so that the user can look on the information on that window to decide which button to click on on the dialog. Like in the following program, when "Dialog" is open, I want to be able to access the "Different Frame". How can I make that work?

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Different Frame", size=(300, 300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        btn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "open frame")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOpenFrame, id=btn.GetId())
        sizer.Add(btn)
        text = "This is a line.\n" * 100
        txtCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, text, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE,
                              size=(200,200))
        sizer.Add(txtCtrl)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def OnOpenFrame(self, evt):
        ParentFrame()

class ParentFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, title="Parent Frame",size=(500, 500))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        btn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "open dialog")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOpenDialog, id=btn.GetId())
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def OnOpenDialog(self, event):
        dlg1 = MyDialog(self)
        val = dlg1.ShowModal()

        dlg2 = MyDialog(self, val)
        dlg2.ShowModal()

class MyDialog(wx.Dialog): 
    def __init__(self, parent, prevAnsw=None): 
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, -1, title = "Dialog") 
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        if prevAnsw is not None:
            sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(
                panel, -1, "Answer from previous Dialog: %s" % prevAnsw))
        sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Try to scroll in Different Frame to "
                                "see if it is blocked"))
        btn1 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Pass 1")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPass1, id=btn1.GetId())
        sizer.Add(btn1)

        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Pass 2")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPass2, id=btn2.GetId())
        sizer.Add(btn2)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnPass1(self, evt):
        self.EndModal(1)

    def OnPass2(self, evt):
        self.EndModal(2)

app = wx.App(0)
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You don't have to show dialogs modally. You can just show them...

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: I know that I can Show() them. But  I need many dialogs to show step by step, in which each step is decided by the result of the previous step. Just Show() dialog it is nothing different than a frame.

Comment: That sounds like a Wizard to me. wxPython has a Wizard widget - https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.adv.Wizard.html

Comment: @MikeDriscoll My gut feel is that a Wizard is modal by nature.

Comment: They are a subclass of `wx.Dialog`, but I am pretty sure you can just `Show` them non-modally if you want to

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: I have tried Wizard. However I have no way to Show wizard non-modally like you said. Thanks anyway for introducing a new widget for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is don't make it a `dialog`.
Below is a a rather inelegant pseudo-dialog, in that it does not return until an action has occurred. It maintains the ability to access other windows by calling `Yield` within the `while` loop that is waiting for an event to take place.
Due to the fact that the other windows are "live", buttons that activate this process have to disabled and re-enabled once each process finishes, so it becomes a bit of a hack really but it should point you in a direction that achieves what you want.
Perhaps it could be written as a ChainDialog module in it's own right but I think that it may well just duplicate the `Wizard` module mention by Mike Driscoll.

```
import wx
import time

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Reference Frame", size=(300, 300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.btn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "open frame")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOpenFrame, id=self.btn.GetId())
        sizer.Add(self.btn)
        text = "This is a line.\n" * 100
        txtCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, text, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE,
                              size=(200,200))
        sizer.Add(txtCtrl)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def OnOpenFrame(self, evt):
        DialogRequest(self)

class DialogRequest(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title="Dialog Request Frame",size=(500, 500))
        self.parent = parent
        #Disable the "open frame" button
        self.parent.btn.Enable(False)

        #Use a dictionary to store chained results
        #Allows for rewriting of results if "Previous" button used
        self.stored_results = {}

        self.dlg_chain_no = 0
        self.dlg_prev_value = 0
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.btn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "open dialog")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOpenDialog, id=self.btn.GetId())
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def OnOpenDialog(self, event):
        self.btn.Enable(False) #Disable open dialog

        #For test purposes there will be 4 chained dialogs
        #result -1 is a cancelled dialog
        #
        while self.dlg_chain_no != 4 and self.dlg_chain_no != -1:
            dlg = ChainDialog(self, self.dlg_chain_no)
            result = ChainDialog.Action(dlg)
            if result.chain_no == -1: # dialog Cancelled zero down stored values
                self.dlg_chain_no = 0
                self.stored_results = {}
                print("Dialog chain Cancelled")
                break
            self.dlg_chain_no = result.chain_no
            self.stored_results[result.chain_no] = result.result
            self.dlg_prev_value = result.result

        self.dlg_chain_no = 0
        self.dlg_prev_value = 0
        print("dialog values", self.stored_results)
        self.stored_results = {}

        self.btn.Enable(True) #Re-enable open dialog

    def OnClose(self, event):
        #Re-enable the "open frame" button
        self.parent.btn.Enable(True)
        event.Skip()

class ChainDialog(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, chain_no):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title = "Dialog "+str(chain_no))
        self.chain_no = self.saved_chain_no = chain_no
        self.result = None
        self.parent = parent
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        if parent.dlg_prev_value != 0:
            sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(
                panel, -1, "Answer from previous Dialog: %s" % parent.dlg_prev_value))
        sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Try to scroll in Different Frame to "
                                "see if it is blocked"))
        btn1 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Step "+str(self.chain_no))
        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Previous")
        btn3 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Cancel")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStep, id=btn1.GetId())
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPrev, id=btn2.GetId())
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCancel, id=btn3.GetId())
        sizer.Add(btn1)
        sizer.Add(btn2)
        sizer.Add(btn3)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()

    def Action(self):
        #Keep this dialog frame open until an action has occurred.
        #The action will be from OnStep, OnPrev or OnCancel
        #Use Yield to allow other frames to be viewed
        #This pseudo-dialog returns self of relevance chain_no and result
        while self.chain_no == self.saved_chain_no:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            wx.GetApp().Yield()
        self.Close()
        return self

    def OnStep(self, evt):
        self.chain_no += 1
        #Return some relevant value or other
        self.result = int(time.time())

    def OnPrev(self, evt):
        self.chain_no -= 1
        #Return some relevant value or other (I'm just using time)
        self.result = int(time.time())

    def OnCancel(self, evt):
        self.chain_no = -1

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: If not showing it like a dialog, it is just like a frame. I show 2 dialogs just to show 2 tasks that the later needs wait for the former to be done before it start. I really need the way a dialog works, but still need a way to review a non related window ("Different Frame").

Comment: @HuongOrchid See my adapted answer, it is by no means the finished article but may help

Comment: I have one way to solve this which is to split OnOpenDialog() into 2 functions and block just the parent frame. I will post it later. But your answer seems to block the parent frame better than mine.  However it is too complicated to understand right away. When I understand that I will accept that as the solution for my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Rolf of Saxony is interesting so I take it as my solution. I also have another simpler answer for this problem in which I split up the function OnOpenDialog() so it can wait in ParentFrame. This idea is actually from the first answer from Roll of Saxony too. I added the option that ParentFrame is blocked when its MyDialogs are open while others are not affected (MyFrame or different Frame). This answer is not really clean but simple, I don't have to change much in my code.

```
import wx

class NonrelatedFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Non-related Frame", size=(300, 300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        btn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "open frame")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOpenFrame, id=btn.GetId())
        sizer.Add(btn)
        text = "This is a line.\n" * 100
        txtCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, text, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE,
                              size=(200,200))
        sizer.Add(txtCtrl)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def OnOpenFrame(self, evt):
        ParentFrame()

class ParentFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, title="Parent Frame",size=(500, 500))
        self.passActivate = None
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        btn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "open dialog")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOpenDialog, id=btn.GetId())
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ACTIVATE, self.OnActivate)

    def OnActivate(self, evt):
        # use self.passActivate and OnActivate() to help make user not
        # be able to access anything on this form
        if self.passActivate is not None:
            self.passActivate.Raise()

    def OnOpenDialog(self, event):
        dlg1 = MyDialog(self, func2call=self.OnOpenDialog2)
        dlg1.Show()

    def OnOpenDialog2(self, val):
        dlg2 = MyDialog(self, prevAnsw=val, lastDialog=True)
        dlg2.Show()

class MyDialog(wx.Dialog): 
    def __init__(self, parent, prevAnsw=None, lastDialog=False, func2call=None): 
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, -1, title = "Dialog", style=wx.CAPTION)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.passActivate = self
        self.lastDialog = lastDialog
        self.func2call = func2call
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        if prevAnsw is not None:
            sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(
                panel, -1, "Answer from previous Dialog: %s" % prevAnsw))
        sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Try to scroll in Non-related Frame to "
                                "see if it is blocked"))
        btn1 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Pass 1")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPass1, id=btn1.GetId())
        sizer.Add(btn1)

        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Pass 2")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPass2, id=btn2.GetId())
        sizer.Add(btn2)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnPass1(self, evt):
        if not self.lastDialog:
            self.func2call(1)
        else:
            self.parent.passActivate = None
        self.Close()


    def OnPass2(self, evt):
        if not self.lastDialog:
            self.func2call(2)
        else:
            self.parent.passActivate = None
        self.Close()


app = wx.App(0)
frame = NonrelatedFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I don't think that your `passActivate` is doing what you think it's doing. You can still access both the `open frame` and `open dialog` buttons.

Comment: I have tried this. I can access "open frame" button but not "open dialog" button because any access on Parent Frame will be passed to Dialog when any Dialog is open. Blocking Parent Frame and leaving Non-related Frame unblocked when Dialogs open is exactly what I want. In case I need to disable "open frame" button like you did, it is not a problem. However I like your solution better because I can deal with different scenarios easier. Thanks a lot.